# [ performance]--- string::operator+= vs. vector<char> push_back

Tags: c++, string, gcc, vector, char

I was testing the performance between these two operations, and on G++ 4.7.3, the string::operator+= version is about 2 times faster. My simple test:
What can be the cause of such a big difference?

g++ -O2 --std=c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Timer {
    public:
    Timer(const std::string &label)
        :label_(label)
    {
        begin_clock_ = clock();
        cout <<label<<"- Timer starts!"<<endl;
    }
    ~Timer() {
        clock_t clock_used = clock() - begin_clock_;
        cout<<label_<<"- Clock used:"<<clock_used
        <<" Time:"<<clock_used/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
    }
    private:
    clock_t begin_clock_;
    string label_;
};

int str(int loop)
{
    Timer t("str");
    string s;
    for(int i=0;i<loop;++i)
        s+=(i%2);
    return s.length();
}
int vec(int loop)
{
    Timer t("vec");
    vector<bool> v;
    for(int i=0;i<loop;++i)
    v.push_back(i%2);
    return v.size();
}

int main()
{
    int loop = 1000000000;
    int s1=str(loop);
    int s2=vec(loop);
    cout <<"s1="<<s1<<endl;
    cout <<"s2="<<s2<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::string` and `std::vector<char>` aren't really the same, and you should expect different behaviors?

Comment: I expected they would have different speed, but was really surprised at the large gap in performance, in this particular case. They both allocate on the heap.

Comment: You should be surprised. But post an MCVE, and be sure to compile in optimized mode.

Comment: Obligatory what optimization/command line options did you use? Those should always be provided for performance questions.

Comment: Did you try switching round the order? Also is optimization on? It pays to repeat the test a few times in a loop also. In my tests they are about the same (string being slightly slower).

Comment: They probably use different allocation schemes. Try calling `reserve(1000000)` first.

Comment: the optimization option definitely changed their relative performance. although I have no idea what happened behind the scene. 

The reason I stumbled upon this is because I simply needed a container to allow fast insertions for char. and the container needs to have a forward iterator. that's it. 
So string and vector<char> came to mind.

Comment: @ijklr is the above code your current one? It uses `vector<bool>` instead of `vector<char>`. Also for me string is 27% slower than the bool vector with -02 and gcc 5.1 **Edit:** changing it to `vector<char>` string is now 62% slower than the vector.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl, oh sorry, that was from my second test. 
I was thinking surely vector<bool> would be faster than string,, but no... string is still faster.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Maybe the difference between your test and mine is because--  I am running on windows using cygwin. 
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.3
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I just tried. reserve still didn't make the vector version faster than string.

Comment: My bet: Your `string` knows that its elements are trivially constructible/destructible, but your `vector<char>` does not. A different (or just newer) compiler will almost certainly make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings and vectors both store their content contiguously. If there's not enough room for adding a new element, the capacity must be increased (memory allocation) and the existing content must be moved to the new location.

Hence, the performance should depend significantly on the allocation strategy of your implementation.  If one container reserves bigger chunks when the current capacity is exhausted, it will be more efficient (less allocation, less moving).

Of course, the results are implementation dependent. In my tests, for example, the vector implementation was one third faster than the string variant.

Here how to see the effect:

```
int str(int loop)
{
    Timer t("str");
    string s;
    size_t capa = 0, ncapa, alloc = 0;   // coutners for monitoring allocations
    long long mw = 0;                    // 
    for(int i = 0; i<loop; ++i){
        if((ncapa = s.capacity()) != capa)  // check if capacity increased
        {                                              // 
            capa = ncapa; alloc++; mw += s.size();     //
        }                                              //
        s += (i % 2);
    }
    cout << "allocations: " << alloc << " and elements moved: " << mw << endl;
    return s.length();
}
```

On my compiler for example, for strings I got a capacity of 2, 4, 8, ... when for vectors it started immediately at 32,64, ...

Now, this doesn't explain all.  If you want to see what part of the performance comes from allocation policy and what from other factors,  you can siimply pre-allocate your string (`s.reserve(loop);`) and your vector (`v.reserve(loop);`) before starting to add any elements.

Comment: interesting, both of my string and vector start with 1,2,4,8, 16, 32, 64 etc.